# Magento Store config strange behavior during custom module installation

Tags: magento, module

Is there some restrictions of access to store configuration during installation of custom module in Magento? Here is the problem

I have an installation script:

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('userpaymentban')};
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('userpaymentban')} (
      `ban_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
      `paymentmethod_id` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
      `store_id` INT NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ban_id`) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;");
    $defaultNotBannedPaymentMethods = array();
    $paymentMethods = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getAllMethods();
```

The query is OK, but last line causes of throwing some wierd thing:

```
    Error in file: "/var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/local/Alpha/Userpaymentban/sql/userpaymentban_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Config.php on line 76

    #0 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
    #1 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '0.1.0')
    #2 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.0')
    #3 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
    #4 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
    #5 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
    #6 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #7 /var/www/magentotest/magento161/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #8 {main}
```

The exception was thrown in `Mage_Payment_Model_Config` in code:

```
    public function getAllMethods($store=null)
{
    $methods = array();
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment', $store);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($config);
echo "</pre>";
    foreach ($config as $code => $methodConfig) {
        $data = $this->_getMethod($code, $methodConfig);
        if (false !== $data) {
            $methods[$code] = $data;
        }
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

As you can see I am already added some debugging code, but all what I receive from that is just `NULL`

My Magento is OK (I think) because when I am using `Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getAllMethods()` out of module installation scope (in a file with imported `app/Mage.php`) I receive a nice list of all payment methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ha, I'm always looking for reasons to justify the existence of *data*-install/upgrade scripts to my Magento U students, and this is another great example.

If you look into the initialization process (starting at `Mage::run()` in `index.php`), you'll arrive quickly at `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()`. In there you'll see a call to `_initModules()`. It's from this method that "regular" install/upgrade scripts are run (via `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()`). Later on in `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()` is a call to `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()`. This is where the data-install/data-upgrade scripts are run, and it's *just after* the store object is initialized via `_initCurrentStore()`.

That seems to be the purpose of the so-called data scripts - you get the store object with its configuration loaded.

These scripts are run/named just like "regular" install/upgrade scripts, with the only difference being that the filenames are `mysql4-data-[install|upgrade]-[version(s)].php` for CE < 1.6 and EE < 1.11. For 1.6/1.11 and up, data scripts lose the mysql4 prefix and are placed in a `data` folder under your module directory (see `Mage_Catalog` dir for an example).

Comment: Ah, this answer saved me.  Was digging around in config model for about 15 minutes trying to hunt this down.  #benmarksforcto

Comment: What if I'm adding a new data-upgrade script? Should I have the file's version and version number in config.xml incremented? I've added data/{module_name}_setup/data-upgrade-0.1.8-0.1.9.php (which is the incremented version number of the module) and updated version number in config.xml to 0.1.9, cleared the cache and the script is not executed. Any thoughts? - Thanks

Comment: @RaduBarbu check the record in `core_resource` table and see if the version number has changed. If not, clear the cache and check it again (script should run). If the record is changed, then there is an issue with the path or filename (which looks correct here). Also, if your Magento version is < 1.4 then data upgrade scripts do not apply.

Comment: @benmarks solved the issue ... it was a script caching issue :(